# does this string contain a word from a different dataset that is shorter? how to create flag

Tags: r

I have a dataset filled with names. I used freq_terms to find the most common names. Now I'd like to flag the names if they are common.

```
df = data.frame(FullName = c("mary berry", "anthony horrowitz", "jennifer lawrence", 
                             "john jones", "red rover", "mick jagger", "king arthur"))

df2 = data.frame(common = c("mary", "john"))

df$common <- mapply(`%in%`, df2$common, df$FullName)

Warning message:
In mapply(`%in%`, df2$common, df$FullName) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

I've tried a couple different variations with grepl and str_detect, and for the life of me I can't get the syntax right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As to why `mapply` throws a warning - your code runs a loop using each value in `common` (length==2) and `Fullname` (length==7) in turn as inputs, which won't match up. You'd need to do something like `mapply(\`%in%\`, df["FullName"], df2$common)` to get something usable - though `mapply(grepl, x=df["FullName"], pattern=df2$common)` would be needed as you're not exactly matching strings.

Comment: `df["FullName"]` being a length == 1 list that will be searched within by each value of `common` in turn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

If you want to compare the 2 data frames, here's one way.

```
library(stringr)

df$common <- sapply(df$FullName, function(x) str_split(x, " ")[[1]][1] %in% df2$common)
```

**OLD ANSWER**

How about:

```
library(stringr)

df$common <- str_detect(df$FullName, "mary|john")
```

Result:

```
           FullName common
1        mary berry   TRUE
2 anthony horrowitz  FALSE
3 jennifer lawrence  FALSE
4        john jones   TRUE
5         red rover  FALSE
6       mick jagger  FALSE
7       king arthur  FALSE
```

Comment: the actual "common" dataset has a few hundred entries, which would be onerous lol

Comment: Perhaps you could create a regex using `common_names <- paste(df2$common, collapse = "|"` ? Not sure how well a very long regex would work though.

Comment: Edited with a different approach.